# Form validation not working (no console errors) and passing parameters through multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form to validate (snippet below)

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal contact-form">

<h2>Contact details</h2>
<h3>Please ensure that these are accurate so that we can contact you if there is a problem processing your request</h3>

<fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="first-name">First name<span class="asterisk">*</span>:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" placeholder="Please enter your first name" />
        </div>
    </div>....
```

I'm having trouble getting my validate function to work and am also curious about passing "e" as a parameter through the functions (if that makes sense)...

Have been racking my brains with this, hopefully someone can spot where I've gone wrong

JS below:

```
    (function(){
    var form     = '.contact-form',
    alert    = $('.alert'),
    fieldWrap = '.control-group',
    error     = 'error',
    errorMsg  = 'error-message',
    show      = 'show',
    hide      = 'hide',
    formValid = false;

var validate = function(field,regEx,e){

    if((regEx).test($(field).val())){
        $(field).parents(fieldWrap).addClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(hide);
        formValid = true;
    }
    else{
        $alert.addClass(show);
        $(field).parents(fieldWrap).removeClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(show);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

};

$(form).on('submit',function(e){
    validate('#first-name',/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    validate('#last-name',/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    validate('#contact-number',/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    validate('#email',/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    validate('#landline-number',/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    validate('#postcode',/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
});
})();
```

The regEx is just to test the fields.

Comment: You don't pass the event `e` to your function, then in the `validate` function it will be `undefined`. $(form).on('submit',function(**e**){. You should also use `$(document).on('click', form, function(e) {...});`

Comment: Thanks.. cant believe I missed that... actual function still not working though :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your function this way, I'm going to write a little explanation in a few minutes.

```
(function () {
    var form = '.contact-form',
        alert = $('.alert'),
        fieldWrap = '.control-group',
        error = 'error',
        errorMsg = 'error-message',
        show = 'show',
        hide = 'hide';

    function validate(field, regEx, e) {
        var element = $(field);
        if (regEx.test(element.val())) {
            element.parents(fieldWrap).addClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(hide);
            return true;
        }
        alert.addClass(show);
        element.parents(fieldWrap).removeClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(show);
        return false;
    };

    function formIsValid() {
        return validate('#first-name', /^[a-zA-Z]{3}/, e) && validate('#last-name', /^[a-zA-Z]{3}/, e) && validate('#contact-number', /^[a-zA-Z]{3}/, e) && validate('#email', /^[a-zA-Z]{3}/, e) && validate('#landline-number', /^[a-zA-Z]{3}/, e) && validate('#postcode', /^[a-zA-Z]{3}/, e);
    }

    $(document).on('submit', form, function (e) {
        if (!formIsValid()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
        console.log("form is valid, submitted.");
        return true;
    });
})();
```

I have refactored your code fastly in the best way I could. This is the explanation of edits:

The validate function has been changed a bit, now it returns true if the field is valid, so that you can write a big function that returns all the validity of the fields, which is `formIsValid`.

```
function validate(field, regEx, e) {
    var element = $(field);
    if (regEx.test(element.val())) {
        element.parents(fieldWrap).addClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(hide);
        return true;
    }
    alert.addClass(show);
    element.parents(fieldWrap).removeClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(show);
    return false;
};
```

As you can see, the submit function is refactored so that has only few logics in it. The big work is done by `formIsValid` which checks all the forms.

```
if (!formIsValid()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
console.log("form is valid, submitted.");
return true;
```

Comment: Great answer, helped me refactor my code and gave me a better understanding of how things work

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

validate function

```
var validate = function(field,regEx,e){
    if((regEx).test($(field).val())){
        $(field).parents(fieldWrap).addClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(hide);
        formValid = true;
        return false; // if error comes then no submit
    }
    else{
        $alert.addClass(show);
        $(field).parents(fieldWrap).removeClass(error).find(errorMsg).addClass(show);
        return true; // return true if valid form
    }

};
$(form).on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    f=validate(fName  ,/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    l=validate(lName  ,/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    en=validate(cNumber,/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    em=validate(email  ,/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    ln=validate(lNumber,/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    pc=validate(pCode  ,/^[a-zA-Z]{3}/,e);
    if(f && l && en && em && ln && pc) // everything is valid then return true
         return true;
    else // false otherwise
         return false;
});
```

Comment: You're doing the exact opposite of the function purpose. Anyway you can change the return of the function to `return f && l && en && em && ln && pc`.

Comment: Thanks, had to modify it slightly but got it to work so 1+ and accepted